# Преобразовать дату JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть дата в виде `26.09.2016`, необходимо получить день недели, вида: `Пн`. Как это можно сделать, не используя плагины?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
var weekDays = ['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб'];
var dateStr = '26.09.2016';
var isoDateStr = dateStr.split('.').reverse().join('-');
var date = new Date(isoDateStr);
console.log(weekDays[date.getDay()]);
```